# Pulling Values from Last Edited Row in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**Details:**

I've created a Google Form which when filled out populates the form data in a new row in a corresponding Google Sheet the Form is attached to.

I've set up a Trigger so that OnFormSubmit, an email is generated with the contents of the form. This works as intended.

Next, the recipient of that email is directed into the Google Sheet, and asked to write some things in the columns to the right of the form data/row referenced in the email. At the end, they write 'Yes' in that row if that row's data is ready to move on in the process.

I've also set up a Trigger OnEdit, so that if that prior user has written 'Yes' in their row, as explained above, another email is generated.

**My problem:**

If multiple forms are submitted back to back, and for example the form data populates rows 2, 3 & 4 in the Google Sheet, and someone enters 'Yes' in Row 2, the OnEdit trigger generates an email, but includes the data from the latest row, Row 4.

**The question:**

How can I make it so if 'Yes' is entered in Row 2, it's the data in Row 2 that gets sent through email, even if there are new form data already in Rows 3, 4, 5, etc?

**Some example code from my Script:**

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues(); // identifies latest row submitted to let...                               
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;     // ...email recipient know which row to look at

  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var row = values.getLastRow();

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy"); 
  var endDate = date; 

  var Title = values.getRange(row, 2).getValue(); // examples of how I'm pulling the data
  var Supervisor = values.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  var Approval1 = values.getRange(row, 17).getValue();
  var Approval2 = values.getRange(row, 18).getValue();

  // to save space I'm not posting the emailbody here - which works as intended using htmlbody 
  // further down in the code, as part of the OnEdit trigger, this is the if statement

  if(Approval1 == "Yes" && Approval2 == "")
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: emailRecipients,
  replyTo: replyToSubmitter,
  subject: emailSubject1,
  htmlBody: emailBodyFirstApproved})
  ;
  }

   else if(Approval1 == "Yes" && Approval2 == "Yes")
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: emailRecipients,
  replyTo: replyToSubmitter,
  subject: emailSubject2,
  htmlBody: emailBodyBothApproved})
  ;
```

Thanks a ton for reading and a million for helping!

Comment: I wouldn't allow users to directly edit anything in the linked sheet.  And infact I would leave the linked sheet totally alone and do any additional work in another sheet loaded from the onSubmitTrigger.

Comment: Like Cooper said, this is more an issue with the approach rather than the code. If you're just asking a yes/no question to the user, why not make it the last question of the Form itself? Also, to avoid the last row issue you should use an `onEdit()` trigger and get the row from the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

Comment: Thanks @Cooper and @Amolina;

Cooper - What do you mean by another sheet loaded from the onSubmitTrigger?

AMolina - There are 4 separate approval steps/users. The user who submits the form is different from the user who then adds some data and types yes/no; After the first yes/no user, there is a THIRD user who comes into the sheet to enter additional information in the row, and enter their own yes/no. Each yes/no generates a new htmlbody and emailrecipients. So - the yes/no can't be part of the original form because there are approvals after the submission.

Comment: Also @Cooper can you please explain the onEdit/event object comment? Sorry, I'm BRAND new to coding/java. My first trigger is onformsubmission, but my 2nd function IS an onEdit trigger [at least when I click the trigger icon] - I basically set it to run the function when there is an edit in the sheet, and then it checks the if statements to decide which htmlbody to send [did approver 1 or 2 say yes?].

Comment: I didn't make any statements here regarding the use of  an onEdit() trigger.

Comment: Regarding my on form submit suggestion I would write a script that takes the data from the on form submit trigger and put it in another spreadsheet to add additional data. And I wouldn’t interfere with the link sheet at all I just leave it alone let it collect data and that way I always have a copy of the raw data. And personally I wouldn’t let other users interact directly with a spreadsheet instead I do it in Web app.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the row value of the *last edited row* by replacing this:

`var var_name = values.getRange(row, 18).getValue();`

With this:

`var var_name = sheet.getRange(index, 2).getValue();`

I found the following code that enabled the above to work:

`var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('sheet name'); 
 var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
 var index = actRng.getRowIndex();`